# Trouble with scala.util.parsing.combinator.ImplicitConversions

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have the following code:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Parser1 extends RegexParsers with ImplicitConversions with PackratParsers {
  lazy val e: PackratParser[Int] = (
      e ~ "+" ~ e ^^ { (e1, _, e2) => e1 + e2 }
    | e ~ "-" ~ e ^^ { (e1, _, e2) => e1 - e2 }
    | """\d+""".r ^^ { _.toInt }
  )
}
```

which doesn't compile:

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
      e ~ "+" ~ e ^^ { (e1, _, e2) => e1 + e2 }
                                   ^
```

The definition of `e` is taken from the [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/nested-blocks.html#parentheses). What I want (and expected) to happen is for the implicit conversion `flatten3` from `ImplicitConversions` to be used automatically. It works if I add it manually:

```
object Parser1 extends RegexParsers with ImplicitConversions with PackratParsers {
  lazy val e: PackratParser[Int] = (
      e ~ "+" ~ e ^^ flatten3({ (e1, _, e2) => e1 + e2 })
    | e ~ "-" ~ e ^^ flatten3({ (e1, _, e2) => e1 - e2 })
    | """\d+""".r ^^ { _.toInt }
  )
}
```

I know it's in scope, has the right type, and works, and it is declared implicit in the Scala source, so why doesn't the compiler use the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 1):

> has the right type

Try adding parameter types:

`{ (e1: Int, _: Any, e2: Int) => e1 + e2 }`

```
object Parser1 extends RegexParsers with ImplicitConversions with PackratParsers {
  lazy val e: PackratParser[Int] = (
      e ~ "+" ~ e ^^ { (e1: Int, _: Any, e2: Int) => e1 + e2 }
    | e ~ "-" ~ e ^^ { (e1: Int, _: Any, e2: Int) => e1 - e2 }
    | """\d+""".r ^^ { _.toInt }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks som-snytt, that does work. I still don't understand why the compiler couldn't figure this out itself though.